# Composer project update

Tags: composer-php

I have creared a project using the following command (Package is irrelevant)

```
composer create-project lorem/lorem .
```

This has done as expected. What I want to acheive is to update this project. I know that the package I have used has incremeneted with a new verision; however when I run

```
composer update
```

It does not update the project, which command am I missing? Or am I just not understanding?

Thanks

Comment: So what does happen? What output do you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running

```
$ composer update
```

doesn't update your project - it updates the *dependencies* of your project, taking into account the version constraints specified in `composer.json`.

For reference, see

- https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#update
- https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/versions.md#versions